# mp3 file gets corrupted after tagging

Tags: mp3, metadata, id3, id3v2, id3-tag

If I downloaded songs from gaana.com, it goes to `SD card\Android\data\com.gaana\files\.gaana` folder without any extension. When I rename the file with .mp3 extension, I am able to play the song in windows media player.

Everything is fine until here. Now when I use softwares like Mp3Tag, EasyTAG and few others to update the album/track/artist and other metadata tag info, it corrupts the mp3 file and it does not play in windows media player.

Can someone tell me the correct way of tagging downloaded mp3 files from gaana.com?

Comment: Are you sure that your songs really are *.mp3? Not *.m4a or *.wma or *.flac or something else?

Comment: I dont know because when I download, it does not have any extension and when I rename the file by putting an extension .mp3, it plays without any issues. It doesnt play if I add tags.

Comment: You can try to check this songs with "Mp3 diags" (from http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/). Maybe this tool identify some problems with your mp3 songs. Without an example song it is hard to guess.

Comment: Thank you... I read the entire page but did not understand where and how to start. Meanwhile, I have uploaded the mp3 file on my google drive. Appreciate if you can have a look at it. Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByCeQNphZOtQSVMtdExYVzdYUXc/view?usp=sharing_eid

Comment: After playing around with it for a while, i saw a message down "Unsupported version of ID3V2 tag - begins with: "ID3h..p and some stuff ahead with few numbers"" I have given a link to download the mp3 file. Please tell me how can I tag it with album name, title, album art image etc. Thanks

Comment: I can't get your file. I should enter UserID and Password for your drive .-)

Comment: The google drive link was set as private. I had set it to public. Now you may download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not a MP3 - according to http://mediaarea.net/de/MediaInfo this song is a MPEG-4 / AAC. You can find more infos about this format in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding

If you rename it to *.aac and then tag your album/track/artist and other metadata info with Mp3tag your song get it correctly and play well.

Comment: Hey... Thanks. I was able to tag the file in mp3tag after renaming it to aac. However, its results are not displayed on windows media player or mobile phone music player. When I play the song, it says unknown album and its album art picutre is also not visible. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how your mentioned software handle this metadata.

Comment: To give you more information, this file was downloaded from http://gaana.com/song/main-jat-yamla-pagla-diwana-7 that went into mobile phone sdcard at SD card\Android\data\com.gaana\files\.gaana Album name is Evergreen Dharmendra, Track is Main Jat Yamla Pagla Diwana Song, Artist is MOHD.RAFI. All tag information is displayed when I play from gaana.com native player. Is there any way to download that info as well along with the song? Or any way to import the tag information and associate with the track? Appreciate your comments on this. Thanks

Comment: Here is the edited file in which tags are entered but not visible in windows media player or mobile phone player https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByCeQNphZOtQTzIzUEMwcVdHWTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As a customer from gaana.com, try to ask them why they don't include the available metadata into the songs. (Maybe some kind of licence restriction?) If this is not possible, the only thing that remains is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: yes.. its a paid player and the tags opens only in their player. My question is that if I have entered the tags manually to the .aac file ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByCeQNphZOtQTzIzUEMwcVdHWTg/view?usp=sharing ) then why it is not showing up on windows media player and mobile phone player. If you download this new file, you will see that the tags are present but not visible. Any idea why it is behaving like that? Or is there any other way to add metadata to .aac files?

Comment: Did you download the .aac file from the link above? Were you able to find why the tags does not show up in WMP? Thanks

Comment: Yes and No. Otherwise I would write a solution .-)

Comment: thank you for your kind support. really appreciate!